# Need Help Help mask

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

I'm having problems with my version 4.0 in sculpting mode and in other addons too, but now I would like to know if anyone here could help me with how to solve this problem

Whenever I put the *Multiresolution* modifier in sculpting mode to optimize the mesh and paint a mask, it keeps painting these squares, this doesn't affect the texture, I've checked it several times

This happens every time I put it in anchoring mode

which is when I paste a certain texture and scale and rotate it from the anchor point

My setup is a 3060 12gb 64gb mr
Before everything was normal but after I formatted my PC, it stayed like this I thought it was the video drive but I'm using the same version as before

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid emojis, using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: If it doesn't affect the texture what is your problem then? I can see nothing wrong with the sculpt.